# XPath text() returns 2 Values how to combine them to one

Tags: xpath

I have this:

```js
const $x = xp => {
  const snapshot = document.evaluate(
    xp, document, null, 
    XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null
  );
  return [...Array(snapshot.snapshotLength)]
    .map((_, i) => snapshot.snapshotItem(i))
  ;
};

console.log($x('//h2/text()[1]'));
console.log($x('//h2/text()[2]'));
```

```html
<h2 _ngcontent-gbb-c105="" class="text-center">HERZLICH WILLKOMMEN <br _ngcontent-gbb-c105=""> BEI DEINER ANKER APP</h2>
```

is there a way to get both `text()[1]` and `text()[2]` joined together so I could do something like this: `//*[text()='HERZLICH WILLKOMMEN BEI DEINER ANKER APP']`

Comment: Why do you select down to the text node level although it seems you just want to select the `//h2` element or its string contents `string((//h2)[1])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply select the `h2` element and then read out its `textContent` property:

```js
const $x = xp => {
  const snapshot = document.evaluate(
    xp, document, null, 
    XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null
  );
  return [...Array(snapshot.snapshotLength)]
    .map((_, i) => snapshot.snapshotItem(i))
  ;
};

console.log($x('//h2')[0].textContent);
```

```html
<h2 _ngcontent-gbb-c105="" class="text-center">HERZLICH WILLKOMMEN <br _ngcontent-gbb-c105=""> BEI DEINER ANKER APP</h2>
```

Or you can use the XPath expression `string((//h2)[1])` but obviously your JavaScript code to use the XPath API then would need to be changed to use a different result type:

```js
const text = document.evaluate('string((//h2)[1])', document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue;

console.log(text);
```

```html
<h2 _ngcontent-gbb-c105="" class="text-center">HERZLICH WILLKOMMEN <br _ngcontent-gbb-c105=""> BEI DEINER ANKER APP</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you :D, didnt know that `string()` was a thing, this will make things way easier xD

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the syntax, but I think this should work:

```
console.log($x('//h2').text());
```